# problem binding functions

Tags: jquery, bind

I call a section of another page in to the parent page like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#subscribe").click(function () {
        $("#singleContent").load('purchaseForm.php #Content');
    });
});
```

no problem there. I am having an issue getting functions inside of 'purchaseForm.php' to run. I've tried the ".live" function, but can only bind that to events like click. I need to hide some things and get this code to run:

```
$('[class^=toggle-item]').hide();
$('[class^=link]').live('click', function(e) {
    $('.toggle-item-' + this.className).slideToggle("fast");
    $('span',this).text(function(i,txt) {
        return txt === "Learn More..." ? "Close" : "Learn More...";
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(function() {
    var $add = $('input.add');
    $add.live('click', function() {
        $add.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

How do I bind the above functions to the .load function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#subscribe").click(function () {
        $("#singleContent").load('purchaseForm.php #Content', function()
        {
            $('[class^=toggle-item]').hide();
            $('[class^=link]').live('click', function(e) {
                $('.toggle-item-' + this.className).slideToggle("fast");
                $('span',this).text(function(i,txt) {
                    return txt === "Learn More..." ? "Close" : "Learn More...";
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });

            $(function() {
               var $add = $('input.add');
               $add.live('click', function() {
                   $add.removeAttr('checked');
                   $(this).attr('checked', true);
               });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: North Creative - perfect was not getting the structure correct. Would you recommend doing it this way or including all functions in an external file as Pointy "pointed" out?

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely externalize it wherever possible.  It's a lot easier to maintain and track.

Answer (score 1):

That's a jQuery bug I reported a while ago. To my knowledge, it's not fixed yet.

I'll find the bug and link it. Specifically, when you use ".load()" with a "context" like that (the selector following the URL), it does not run `<script>` tags in the content that's loaded.

*edit* — ok [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6307) is the bug.

To make your setup work, probably the best thing would be to have that code in the surrounding page that loads the content.

Comment: Well, a couple ways: first, I avoid doing that :-)  Second, I try to make it so that all my pages have the same code available, as much as possible in external .js files.

Comment: good point. I should use one external js file for this set of pages that houses all the functions. thx man.